# Generate shared library name via CMake

Tags: cmake

I am trying to add post build event for my project in CMakeLists file.
This post-build event must put Qt libraries near my executable file.
I use `add_custom_command` to do it:

```
set(libraryFileName ${QtDir}/bin/${packageName}.dll)

# Copy qt library after build
add_custom_command(
    TARGET ${target} POST_BUILD             #Path to cmake executable file
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E           #CMake in command mode
        copy                                #Copy command
        "${libraryFileName}"                #Path to the file
        "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${target}>"      #Where to copy
    COMMENT "Copying to output directory")
```

The main problem is how to generate libraryFileName correctly for every system? I mean, my soultion works for Windows, but it will fail for other systems types, I guess. Is there any way to get the extension for shared library instead of hardcoding it?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for my case. But it may work for Qt only.

```
# Get package location
get_target_property(location ${qtVersion}::${shortPackageName} LOCATION)

# Copy qt library after build
add_custom_command(
    TARGET ${target} POST_BUILD             #Path to cmake executable file
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E           #CMake in command mode
        copy                                #Copy command
        "${location}"                       #Path to the file
        "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${target}>"      #Where to copy
    COMMENT "Copying ${packageName}...")
```

Comment: Can't you just use `$<TARGET_FILE:${qtVersion}::${shortPackageName}>` as a source location for `copy`?

Comment: Just remembered that there is also a [policy CMP0026](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0026.html) which will "disallow use of the LOCATION property for build targets" and will give a warning/error in newer versions of CMake.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a platform checker and set the variable depending on that check.

```
message(STATUS "Current CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}")

if("${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}" STREQUAL "WIN98")
   set(libraryFileName ${QtDir}/bin/${packageName}.dll)
elseif("${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}" STREQUAL "LINUX")
   set(libraryFileName ${QtDir}/bin/${packageName}.so)
else
   message(ERROR "The system ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} is not supported.")
endif()
```

Comment: What about using [`CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX.html) for a more generic approach?